# Customizing the Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) error messages (yellow screen of death)

Tags: asp.net, wif, windows-identity, yellow-screen-of-death

WIF will send our users the Yellow Screen of Death whenever an error occurs.  This can be something such as a token replay, or a old token being sent to the server as shown below:

[image]

> How do I customize the display of this error and also log the instances when it occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the errors that happen during the authentication stage (i.e. outside of your code) rather than errors occurring during normal execution (which you could catch with a try - catch) and then do whatever you want.

One way is to use customErrors in the web.config. Refer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355).

In terms of tracing, there is a section in the web.config (system.diagnostics) which you can uncomment. Change "Verbose" to "Error".

Also refer [WIF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517282.aspx) or the WIF section of [How to Enable Verbose Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) Tracing for Claims-Based Authentication](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3459.aspx)